Modeling cap for complex surface
I have the relevant part selected in the image 1 attached. Now I need to model a cap that fits tightly onto it. Basically I want to copy the mesh and scale it on the xy-plane slightly so that the new mesh has about 0.2mm of space to the old mesh, otherwise no distortion of the mesh. It’s meant for 3d printing and one part needs to fit neatly on top of the other with 0.2mm of spiel.

What is the easiest way to do this? Up until now I modeled it by hand which becomes cumbersome and takes a lot of time to truly fit. I was wondering if it can be done with a customized scale operation. For example, scaling along the line in the middle of the mesh (image 2) would be great, but I see only scaling options that change the pivot point. Is it possible to scale along a customized line? and if not, do you know another “elegant” way to approach this problem?


I found the solution by using solidify modifier. Select the faces you want to cap. Copy them, make the copy a new object. Use solidify modifier, set thickness to the distance you want and offset to 1. Delete inside faces of the new object.
